# Azure VM Image Joined To Domain

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Classic Virtual Machine in Azure, sysprepped it, and extracted a VM Image. The image itself works great, except for a newly created VM not being on the domain. I joined the source VM to the domain before sysprepping and capturing the image, so I'm not sure why I have to rejoin when I create a VM from the image.

Answer (score 0):

When I follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/capture-image) to capture windows VM, the newly created VM **not** in the domain,same as your scenario.

Your VM is classic virtual machine, so we can use [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) to capture image, without run sysprep, in this way, the new created VM will join the domain.

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance:)